# Perl Excel::Writer::XLSX - set column format/merge cells dynamically

Tags: excel, perl

I am using Excel::Writer::XLSX to create an Excel file from an array of arrays.  Right now I'm trying to create a formatted table from the data (as much as I can, as opposed to just spitting it back into another file).

First off, when I use set_column() to set the background color, that color is formatted for the entire column.  Is there a way to specify to only go as far as the content in the file goes?  Unfortunately, when the program is run it is dynamic each time and unknown what the final row in the table should be.

Second, is there a way to merge cells based on the content inside of them?  This has to do with the dynamic problem again, there is an optimal output if all the data I am gathering is online. If that were the case I could easily set a range of what these merged cells should be.  But for example, if I have 10 rows of column 2 saying 'A' and then 10 rows of column 2 saying 'B', I would like to merge the A's and B's together.  The issue is that is is unknown if it will always have 10 rows with that value inside of it.

Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

> First off, when I use set_column() to set the background color, that color is formatted for the entire column. Is there a way to specify to only go as far as the content in the file goes?

No. You will have to have to add the format to the cells as you write them.

> But for example, if I have 10 rows of column 2 saying 'A' and then 10 rows of column 2 saying 'B', I would like to merge the A's and B's together.

This isn't possible with Excel::Writer::XLSX. (In fact I don't think it is possible in Excel without using macros).

Since both of your issues relate to not knowing the size and value of the data beforehand then perhaps you could first read your data into an array of arrays, process it to find the required format dimensions and merge ranges and then write them out.